# How prevent combine scss files in webpack compiling?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-style-loader

Good day guys. I dont understand why webpack compile 2 different .scss files

[image]

in one .css file

[image]

How prevent combine in compiling?

This is my webpack config file:

```
module.exports = {
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
        publicPath: '/dist/',
        filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js'
    },
    module: {
        noParse: /es6-promise\.js$/,
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'vue-style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ],
            },

            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: isProd
                    ?
                    [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader']
                : ['vue-style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: isProd
        ? [
            new VueLoaderPlugin(),

            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: 'common.[chunkhash].css'
            })
        ]
        : [
            new VueLoaderPlugin(),
            new FriendlyErrorsPlugin()
        ]
}
```

some text to start ask

Comment: One of the main purposes of webpack/any web bundler is to minimze the number of files to download. What's wrong with having only one CSS file?

Comment: Critical css going to <head> in <style> tag for optimize loading.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you here. Whatever the number of files, you can set them wherever you want in your pages to trigger the download when it is the most adapted. Anyway, the purpose of webpack is to have one big file rather than several small ones, so if you want to have one css file per scss file, better not to use webpack and just compile them with SASS, right?